# Animated GIF images are glitching (animating but most of the frames are blank white)

Tags: bug, images, imgur

I encountered this issue first maybe 1-2 weeks ago on some of my older post (on [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tour), but the images were displayed correctly later on after a few days, so I let it pass). However, all newly added animated GIF images in Stack Overflow in my posts are glitching the same way. Here an example (of an answer I am currently working on):

- [Look at the bottom of the answer (last image)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67685888)

Here the same image (just copied the link):

- [animated GIF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNaLc.gif)

And the same link as an image:

[image: animated GIF image]

The problem is that the GIF image is showing blank (white color) for a long time and only then start animating, but only a few frames and get blank again.

What is happening? Is this a *site* problem or is it my *browser* again?

I am using Opera version:76.0.4017.123 on Windows 7 64 bit

I hope it's not another "feature(d) bug)" added to browsers like this:

- [Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082881/2521214)

I also tried to clear the browser history. However, after that (while writing this answer) this happened:

```
Too many requests
This IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) has performed an unusual high number of requests and has been temporarily rate limited. If you believe this to be in error, please contact us at team@stackexchange.com.
```

While I looked for the linked answer above (had to find it with Google Search instead) I have stored the error message in case it's needed (just comment me and I will mail it)... However, after a few minutes the first linked *answer* page crashed and was able to continue editing and posting this answer.

**[Update1]**

Thanks to other users we **narrowed this issue to the browser misrendering GIF images** (no relation to SO/SE sites) So it's most likely related to depending on undocumented third-party GIF extension chunks similar to the looping issue completely disregarding compatibility with the original GIF file format.

So the "bad" remedy is to reprocess a GIF image in some gfx app that adds these chunks so browsers can display ... in other words all old GIF images are unusable anymore just like when the NETSCAPE looping extension become required.

**[Update2]**

I created a **report bug** issue for the Opera browser. They auto respond was that the bug is enqueued. However, they will not notify on it any further, so only time will tell if they repair this or not.

Comment: Have you disabled hardware acceleration in your browser?

Comment: The gifs are broken for me as well, so if anything they are already broken when I download them from imgur.

Comment: @AndrewMorton not yet will need to find it first ... meanwhile do yo usee the GIFs without blank white? on both this meta and in the SO (first link near `And finally preview (using sky texture for both sky and ground):`)

Comment: @AndrewMorton GIF is OK after redownload ... However if I view it in Opera (localy from hard drive) its rendered with the same glitch so its definaltely Browser related

Comment: @AndrewMorton HW acceleration off showing the same problem. meanwhile after last edit by rene the GIF here on this meta question shows as image (with the blank white, before was just an imgur icon for not working images...)

Comment: Because you copied a link to your answer, not to the image.

Comment: @rene Ahh must miss-happen when the SO connection crashed as I remember clearly copying ling to image ... or just Windows ignored CTRL+C (which does a lot due to badly written ISR for keyboard handling and still not repaired from w9x times) and used last clipboard which hold the question link ...

Comment: Just downloaded and saved the GIF to another program...is it meant to be displayed as below?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWH93.gif

Comment: @Nimantha Yes this works but the GIF is preprocessed to extent I can not see what extention chunks was added to make them work? ... why they constantly corrupt GIF presentation in browsers anyway?

Comment: @Nimantha what program you did use? In case Opera does not fix it so I have something to test on to determine which new chunks are required from now on ...

Comment: @Spektre: ScreenToGif, it's open source... and free :) the [official tutorial](https://www.screentogif.com/how-to-use); also, here were the settings I had used -  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxcsg.png

Answer (score 2):

It must be something on your end as my uploaded animated GIF works:

[image: GIF which shows question, meta post, GIF by itself]

Here is what the first frame in HEX shows me for the extension (I think)

[image: hex]

Comment: What GIF extentions is the GIF using? mine are using only the Netscape looping appart of the its a native GIF

Comment: @Spektre I'm afraid I don't know but skimming over your questions on SO I concluded you're the expert here, not me. I'll check if I can find that.

Comment: @Spektre added the hexdump with I think the info you need.

Comment: Its a finding a needle in stack ... I created an Issue for Opera  lets see what they respond with ... but I am afraid they just used some lib which after update broke native GIF compliant images again like in the past for this issue (without any repair simply by broking all GIFs that where created before without the same lib tools) and are no able to help at all...